# How to Learn MFC C++ 2013

Tags: mfc, visual-studio-2013

I used to develop Application for Android as well as Windows Phone.

I also have a good grip on .NET(C#) and PHP but, now I have to develop an Application using **MFC C++ on Visual studio 2013**.

I'm not good with C++ so, I had read books like:
* Ivor Horton's Beginning Visual C++ 2012
* Professional C++, 3rd Edition.

But there isn't a detailed guideline about MFC classes and MFC application Development life-cycle.

So, I wanna know is there any way to learn MFC 2013

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the books on MFC are old, at least the good ones. So first thing is don't feel bad about the age of the books out there and for that reason you probably wouldn't find a good book with VS2013 or even VS2010. Here are your best choices.

1. [Programming Windows by Charles Petzold](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/157231995X)
2. [Programming Windows with MFC by Jeff Prosise](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1572316950)

No-1 is not about about MFC but I am including this for 'nice to read or for reference' because MFC is wrapper of Windows APIs so it makes easier to understand (if you want to go in-depth) what it wraps.

Comment: First of all Thanks a lot for your suggestion. yesterday, I've surf INTERNET about finding some info. about MFC but, I've found that every topic you search on google, You'll find result about minimum 10 years old. so, I honestly want to know that is that good choice to go with MFC?

Comment: Quite frankly it is not a good choice to learn it because like you noted it is old framework. The learning curve is also steep.

Comment: Yeah! Bro, You're Right and again Thanks a lot for you suggestion.

Comment: Just to add in, this answer is spot on. I'm been programming with C#, Perl and all kinds of apps. I gave petzold's bible a look a long time ago. Now when it came having to use MFC someone handed me Jeff Prosise's book mentioned here. MFC has been updated but the core both MFC and win32 api has remained same so it doesn't break tons of existing code out there. I'm find more and more that those two books are just the best there is.